# WebGL pink error in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, pixi.js

I am trying to write simple 'game' [from this side](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixi-js-tutorial-getting-started/) using pixie.js.

I tried to run it via google chrome, however I am getting strange error:

[image]

What can I do to solve it?

**EDIT**

Error in index.js:225 stands for this:

```
isWebGLSupported: function ()
{
    var contextOptions = { stencil: true };
    try
    {
        if (!window.WebGLRenderingContext)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', contextOptions) || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl', contextOptions);

        return !!(gl && gl.getContextAttributes().stencil);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        return false;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error, as another user stated. It's the welcome message that appears by default on any page with the pixi.js library loaded.

If you want to hide that message, you can add this to your page:

```
<script>
PIXI.utils._saidHello = true;
</script>
```